# Google Dirve: transfer ownership and save to specific folder

Tags: permissions, google-drive-api

Currently I can transfer ownership of a file and save this file to the owner's root using this request

[POST] [https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{FILE_ID}/permissions?moveToNewOwnersRoot=true&transferOwnership=true](https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/%7BFILE_ID%7D/permissions?moveToNewOwnersRoot=true&transferOwnership=true)

(https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create)

I don't wannt the transfered file is located in root or "My dirve".

Is there any way to transfer ownership and save the file to a different directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value of `moveToNewOwnersRoot` is `false` so you can omit it from the POST request.

```
[POST] https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{FILE_ID}/permissions?transferOwnership=true
```

This should retain the file's parent structure upon transfer of ownership.

**UPDATE:**

I see that your original intent is, e.g. a file that you want to transfer ownership has a parent "MyFolder" in your MyDrive, and you want to have the same "MyFolder" parent on the recipient's MyDrive.

Currently, the `Permissions: create` request cannot do that, since the two folders have separate ID's. You (or the recipient) have to create the folder either manually or by API and set it as the parent of the transferred file.

Comment: I tested using that value, but it only retains the parent structure in the origin, but i would like to retain that structure in the other account

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Kindly let me know if this solved your issue or there are problems. Thank you.